# Trying change Button Title and label.center.x in UIView.animate when press button but stuck. Why? Swift 4 Xcode 9.4

Tags: swift, button, label, xcode9.4

**My Problem**

I'm trying do some animation with label using UIView.animate(..) when touchInside button . Everything still be OK until I added a line: "self?.confirm.setTitle("Đăng nhập", for: .normal). The animation doesn't work.

**My Will**

I want the yellow underline below **Đăng Ký** switch to below **Đăng nhập**.

**It good when code is**

```
@IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender:Any?){
    if (signup == false){
        signup = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {[weak self] in
            self?.underlineSignup.center.x -= (self?.underlineSignup.bounds.width)!
           self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
@IBAction func signInAction(_ sender:Any?){
    if (signup == true){
        signup = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {[weak self] in
            self?.underlineSignup.center.x += (self?.underlineSignup.bounds.width)!
            self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[It work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1iVS.png)

**But when I add .setTitle**

```
@IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender:Any?){
    if (signup == false){
        signup = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {[weak self] in
            self?.underlineSignup.center.x -= (self?.underlineSignup.bounds.width)!
            self?.confirm.setTitle("Đăng ký", for: .normal)
            self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
@IBAction func signInAction(_ sender:Any?){
    if (signup == true){
        signup = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {[weak self] in
            self?.underlineSignup.center.x += (self?.underlineSignup.bounds.width)!
            self?.confirm.setTitle("Đăng nhập", for: .normal)
            self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[It stuck, only the title of button confirm change, the underline doesn't move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNfFx.png)

Please anyone can explain this situation.

**EDIT:**

The animation working but it's destination is always the first place which under **Đăng ký** ( animation come from left or right of it, the result always first place )

Comment: Can you set the title to another string like "hello"?

Comment: yes I can, that words mean sign in and sign up in Vietnamese

Comment: What I am asking is: does the app work fine when you use a string having latin glyphs only?

Comment: I changed all to latin glyphs (ex: setTitle("ok") all of above and mainboard) but it still be

Answer (score 0):

I think I knew how it is. Because in setTitle has updateFrame Constraintlayout of view. I have a contraintlayout when build button.
When I setTitles it reset the view using constraint.
That's what I think about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting 'setTitle' into completion.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

       self?.underlineSignup.center.x -= (self?.underlineSignup.bounds.width)!
       self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }){

               //completion
             self?.confirm.setTitle("Đăng ký", for: .normal)


        }
```

Comment: I did it but nothing change